# can I adapt the stand for a Samsung monitor to be used with other monitors?

Tags: display, vesa

I have a Samsung monitor stand that I got off of a monitor similar [to this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NBA9Q6). I was thinking I could get an adapter plate (75 to 100 VESA adapter) and use that stand for one of my other monitors that's not height adjustable.

However, the stand's adapter plate has two screws and two tabs. It looks like it'll be tough to use with an adapter plate, since the plates have four screws for the stand side and four for the monitor side.

Is it possible to re-use this monitor stand?

I can supply pictures if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How good are you at fabricating? Drill and tap the adapter plate to match the four hole pattern.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a 4 hole pattern on the stand, as I explained. Also, those plates are easy to buy and cost about 20 bucks.

Comment: Can you drill the stand? When you need a hole, make one. I've had to do this on countless pieces of networking equipment and bays to fit things where ILECs have wanted them in COs. Usually everything can be drilled if its just a matter of lining up holes.